# How do I setup an Esplora instance for local testing

Tags: electrum-server, lightning-development-kit

How can I setup a local instance of https://github.com/Blockstream/electrs, for example to test/experiment with the Esplora backend for syncing BDK or LDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup a local instance running in the `regtest` network, you basically just have to run `bitcoind -regtest` as usual, and then  follow the instructions given by the [`electrs` installation instructions](https://github.com/Blockstream/electrs#installing--indexing):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/blockstream/electrs && cd electrs
$ git checkout new-index
$ cargo run --release --bin electrs -- -vvvv --daemon-dir ~/.bitcoin
```

However, you have to give a `--network=regtest` to the last command and possibly need to adapt you bitcoin dir.

After the chain made some progress, the log outputs of `electrs` will spit out localhost addresses you can give to BDK, LDK transaction sync, or just an instance of [`rust-esplora-client`](https://github.com/bitcoindevkit/rust-esplora-client):

> INFO - REST server running on 127.0.0.1:3002

(Note that an Electrum RPC address is also given in case you prefer to use the Electrum protocol)

Comment: This is how I startup my `bitcoind` for regtest testing, I also enable filters for any CBF testing:


`mkdir -p /tmp/regtest1/bitcoind;
bitcoind -datadir=/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind -regtest -server -fallbackfee=0.0002 -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -blockfilterindex=1 -peerblockfilters=1 -daemon
`

For cookie authentication the file is at `/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind/regtest/.cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example if using Polar.

`cargo run --release --bin electrs -- -vvvv --daemon-dir ~/.polar/networks/1/volumes/bitcoind/backend1/ --network=regtest`

Answer (score 0):

Nigiri is another way of doing it https://nigiri.vulpem.com/ though it comes with other things that you probably want to run yourself